# Fast algorithm for function minimization

Tags: optimization, minimization

Hello I would like to optimize (in my case find the minimum of) a function efficiently. If R is the set of real numbers, then my function goes from R^n to R, so it is a real-valued function with n real variables. In my case n is between 2 and 10 (but usually its gonna be 4 or 5.

I found many optimization algorithms, but in my specific case, the function is very costly to evaluate, so some are not tailored, in the sense that they need a great amount of evaluations to be efficient.

In my problem, each evaluation is in fact a CFD simulation that can take up to twenty minutes. Also, I would like this function minimization to occur during (or after) a main optimization process that has a budget of 1000 function evaluations tops.

The minimization process should then not take as much evaluations, and if it occurs during my main optimization, I would like my minimization algorithm to be efficient with a limit of 50 function evaluations for example (or a bit more if needed).

I do not seek to find the global minima at all cost, but at least to minimize my function satisfactorily within a relatively small budget of function evaluations (50 to 100).

Could someone lead me to one of those algorithms, if they ever exist ?
Thanks and regards, TOP1.

Comment: Unless the function to be minimized has a trivial shape, you need a lot of points to be able to find a good minimum value, especially in high-dimentional spaces. I think the result of a CFD simulation is very unlikely to result in a trivial function to minimize. You should not expect algorithms to find results human cannot. So the answer is simply that there is no such algorithm AFAIK (1000 points might be enough for R, but not for R^3).

Comment: Is this possible for you to run a less precise simulation so to be able to perform far more evaluations? Once you find area of the function that are small, you can run more exact simulation to tune the result.

Comment: To be more precise, I do not expect to find the glocal minima, but at least to be able to efficiently decrease my function. Also, my value of n is not that great (from 2 to 10 tops), I will edit in case of.

Comment: The idea of making a less precise simulation (coarser mesh for example) is a good idea indeed,. In my case the mesh is already coarse, but I may consider your idea !

Comment: On pretty good approach should be to try to approximate the function based on the current gathered points and then choose the point that minimize the approximation so to improve the approximation iteratively. The better the approximation the better the final solution. Thus, the next question is how to perfectly approximate the function based on the point so far. They are many ways to do it regarding what you know about the target function (eg. spline approximation, Lagrange polynomials).

Comment: This solution is sub-optimal because having a bad set of points in the beginning can completely ignore large area of the search space. Fundamentally, there is always a trade off between exploration and performance in machine learning systems. Since you do not have a lot of points (N=1000). One approach is to pick like N/2 equally spaced points to get a "good" approximation and then pick N/2 points based on the optimal points from the approximation. Other factors might be better (eg. 2N/3 and N/3).

Comment: Randomization might help not to be stuck in a local minima if the approximation fail to approximate some area precisely enough. For example, a simulated-annealing like method where the probability is defined by the approximation function, or a something close to a stochastic beam search. Any general property about the target function can certainly drastically help to find a better algorithm. Math and modelling helps much more than trial-and-error methods.